# Typescript extract generic from instance

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class that uses a generic.

```
class Event<P> {
 constructor( public eventName: string ) {}

 createPayload( payload: P ) {
   return payload
 }
}
```

I would like TypeScript to *infer* the generic used from the instance, so that I do not have to redefine the type.

```
const attackEvent = new Event<{ power: number }>("attack")
```

Since I have defined the generic  here, I would like it to be *inferred* from the `attackEvent` instance:

I have a service that expects a generic, here is an example of the expected use:

```
pubSubService.publish<T>()
```

This is the ideal way that I would like to *infer* the generic from `Event`:

```
pubSubService.publish< attachEvent >( attackEvent.createPayload({ po}) )
```

**This does not work** , and I understand why. I do not understand how to make something like this work .

Comment: It will help potential answerers if you'll provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can use the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) for an improved TS environment.

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use the generic parameter in the constructor, so you would have to pass in the payload already on construction.

```js
class Event<P> {
    public constructor(private payload: P, public eventName: string ) {}

    public updatePayload(payload: P): void {
        this.payload = payload;

        return this.payload;
    }
}


const attackEvent = new Event({ power: 10 }, "attack");
```